# How to go back to my old sentences after deleting them?

Tags: texmaker, shortcut

I am using latex to write my report, papers and everything. However, sometimes I wrote many sentences and deleted them accidently. Then, I can go back to them using `ctrl`+ `z`. Suppose, I write a paragraph. Then, do some changes and then I thought for a while that I should not do these changes. So, I use `ctrl` + `z` to back to my old paragraph, after that, I am pretty sure I was correct with my changes. So, how can I go back to those changes? That is, what is the opposite short cut of `ctrl` + `z`?

Any help please?

Comment: @bmv amazing. Honestly, it is the first time for me to know that. I am a mac user and windows as well. I am using texmaker. editor. Could you please write you comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It very much depends on your editor. It might be `ctrl+y` or `ctrl+shift+z`, but there is no general rule.

Comment: It will save my time!!